# Prompt user in command prompt

Tags: java, gradle, command-prompt

I'm currently working on a program that takes information form google sheets and runs calculations. I use "gradle -q run" to run my program and I want it to prompt the user inside the terminal. Right now I am using scanner but it says "Enter your name: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" when I run instead of waiting for me to add a input, How do I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();

        // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
        // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
        String spreadsheetId = "1Pfs-EpysJZXibe1pHiPLEx8cOCC86H5he5ouApejqiE";
        String range = "Sheet1!A:E";

     // create a scanner so we can read the command-line input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //  prompt for the user's name
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");

        // get their input as a String
        String username = scanner.nextLine();

        // prompt for their age
        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");

        // get the age as an int
        int age = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(String.format("%s, your age is %d", username, age));


        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Dominik's Awesome Script Says:");
          System.out.println("");
          for (List row : values) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-get-user-input-values.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    username = scanner.nextline();
}
```

It worked for me on https://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: It doesn't wait for me to type though it just sees that the condition is false and keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using: [io.Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/Console.html)

Sample:

```
Console console = System.console();
String name = console.readLine("Enter your name: ");
Scanner ageScanner = new Scanner(console.readLine("Enter your age: ");
int age = ageScanner.nextInt();
```